# Automate app icon / splash screen linking in react-native (possibly with rnpm)?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm facing an issue where I need to manually add app icons and splash screens through xCode and android studio, and was wondering if this process can be automated, you can assume that I have all required asset sizes available.

I was trying to find something online that might use rnpm aka `react-native link` to do this, this way it could be easily set up via command line. While doing my research I stumbled upon following:

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
        "src/assets/fonts"
    ]
}
```

This goes into `package.json` and essentially links my custom fonts to xCode and android, really neat feature in my opinion as before I had to do it manually as well, hence I am thinking something like this can be possible for app icon and splash screen maybe?

**UPDATE: (more info based on some answers)**

---

Yeh, I used ionic some time ago, but it doesn't achieve what I am asking for, it just resizes the images, I on the other hand have all resized files already available, all I need to do is somehow link them to xCode and android to tell them that these are the files they should use for icons and splashcreen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in luck, [I wrote a generator](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/tree/master/generators/assets) with this exact goal in mind, and just published a new version.

It generates your assets and it also adds them correctly to your ios and android project.

## Install it

You need `node >= 6` installed and `image-magick`.

Then install the [generator](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox) with

```
npm install -g yo generator-rn-toolbox
```

## Use it

You need:

- a square icon file of more than 200px size
- a square splash image file of more than 2208px size (On Android, as of now, the generator only supports a splash with a plain background color)

Then in your React Native project, run:

```
yo rn-toolbox:assets --icon <path to your icon> --splash <path to your splash>
# For instance
yo rn-toolbox:assets --icon ../icon.png --splash ../splash.png
```

When you are asked to overwrite files, reply with `Y`.

#### And that's it!

Hope it can be useful for others :)

Feel free to [post an issue](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/issues) if you have a problem or any question!
I will take any opportunity to make it the best tool to suit your needs.

Comment: Any chance you could point to a source of your project that handles moving these assets to appropriate places in android and ios folders?

Comment: Yes, of course! Source for asset generation is [here](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/blob/master/generators/assets/imageGenerator.js)
Source for config file moving is [here](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/blob/master/generators/assets/index.js#L84)
Why, if I may ask? :) What do you need?

Comment: just curiosity, as this question was originally about automating this "move" process

Answer (score 0):

Cannot really help but I know Ionic is doing that (with 'npm resources'), and it generates icon and splashscreen. Sorry I can't help more...

Comment: Yeh, I used ionic some time ago, but it doesn't achieve what I am asking for, it just resizes the images, I on the other hand have all resized files already available, all I need to do is somehow link them to xCode and android to tell them that these are the files they should use for icons and splashcreen.